# onclick make changes after refresh of page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this submit button calling onBeforeEventRender function
`<input type="submit" value="Sumbit" name="submit" onclick="onBeforeEventRender();" />`

function:

```
dp.onBeforeEventRender = function(args) {
    var start = new DayPilot.Date(args.e.start);
    var end = new DayPilot.Date(args.e.end);
    var today = new DayPilot.Date().getDatePart();
    var now = new DayPilot.Date();
    var job = args.e.job;
    var barColor = "#aaaaaa";
    var input = document.getElementById("port").value;


    if (args.e.port == input) {
        args.e.backColor = 'green';
    } else if (args.e.port !== input && args.e.active == 1) {
        args.e.backColor = 'red';
    }
};
```

Main var is `var input = document.getElementById("port").value;`
which is getting value from my searchbox. 
When I press submit button nothing changed, but after page refresh, cells with port == input will changed their backColor.
Why is this happening after refresh? Or is there anything which makes my button do onClick function and refresh page automatically?

Thank you ;)

Comment: it's a `submit` button so it will submit the form by default which reloads the page ( unless the action is set to a different page / script ) so if you don't want it to reload the page, use `event.preventdefault()` ??

Comment: I mean, I want to change colour when button is pressed.NOT after refresh

Comment: and for that do you need to submit the form?

Comment: what other type can I use?

Comment: if you simply want to trigger the javascript function by clicking the button change it's type to button ~ ie `<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='onBeforeEventRender()' />`

Comment: Still no change. I have to refresh page too.

Comment: I don't know what `backColor` is supposed to be, it definitely isn't in the DOM. Have you tried `style.backgroundColor` instead?

Comment: that is my argument to color background of my cell. I put alert() in if else statement and it show after refresh. So it means that button is not calling my function. This function is rendering events into calendar. Full name is dp.onBeforeEventRender = function(args)